# I'm trying to display a list of object on my HTML

Tags: reactjs, supabase

countries contains datasets I want to display on my page. When I console.log(item.name), I get that dataset but when I try to return that dataset to an HTML page. I'm getting this error `Error: Objects are not valid as a React child`

```js
  test = async () => {
    let { data: countries, error } = await supabase
    .from('countries')
    .select('name')
    countries.map(item => {return item.name})
  }
```

Comment: could you add your dataset sample or a codesandbox would be even better

Comment: You are propobly returning a plain object data rather then a react child aka some html code. Since you did not give us anything to work with - we do not know. But in this case, a component HAS to return something to the view even an empty fragment works. it cant return just some object such as `item.name`. If you want to return and display the items name then `return <>{item.name}</>` would do the trick. but again, it hightly depends on what you have going on.